# Rails Admin render exceptionally slow in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rails-admin

I am running Rails Admin, with Rails API in production with docker. For some reason, the rendering is extremely slow. A simple page load takes 15 seconds, it seems the rendering of the layouts which is taking an exceptionally long time.

Am I forgetting to compile assets somewhere in the docker build process, that is causing this?

```
User Load (18.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY users.id desc LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 20], ["OFFSET", 0]]
    (20.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
    Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml within layouts/rails_admin/application (Duration: 1559.2ms | Allocations: 49878)
    Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2views/layouts/rails_admin/_head.html.haml (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 190)
    Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2views/layouts/rails_admin/_secondary_navigation.html.haml (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 269)
    Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2views/layouts/rails_admin/_navigation.html.haml (Duration: 3.2ms | Allocations: 469)
    Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2views/layouts/rails_admin/_sidebar_navigation.html.haml (Duration: 35.2ms | Allocations: 17042)
    Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2views/layouts/rails_admin/pjax.html.haml
    Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2views/layouts/rails_admin/pjax.html.haml (Duration: 12.1ms | Allocations: 1683)
    Completed 200 OK in 2302ms (Views: 1590.1ms | ActiveRecord: 120.6ms | Allocations: 77826)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2666) on Github, you could try disabling statistics like so

```rb
RailsAdmin.config do |c|
  c.actions do
    dashboard do
      statistics false
    end
  end
end
```

Full documentation of this is [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Dashboard-action#disabling-record-count-bars).